# CalDAV API access to Google Calendar

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, caldav

I'm trying to access Google Calendar with CalDAV API, but I'm not sure how introduction of Google Calendar API v3 impacts CalDAV interface.

Google Calendar API enforces login & user consent screen to grant access to calendar scope. Can CalDAV bypass that?

I would like to access google calendar by passing credentials only.

If CalDAV can help me here, can you point me to relevant sample or documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Vinay

Answer (score 0):

Both CalDAV and Calendar APIv3 require Oauth2 and so passing credentials directly is not an option. Here is the Google CalDAV documentation: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/caldav/v2/guide

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your inputs. Can you refer me to a basic sample using CalDAV API? I cannot find any.

Comment: It's defined in RFC 4791 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4791 ). There are a few samples around, for example here: http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/